# Review flags doesn't match actual flags

Tags: bug, flagging, 10k-tools

Occasionally the 10K tools show up in my TeX.SE "status bar" showing the number of suggested flags to review:

[image]

The above indicates that there are 8 flags up for review. However, clicking it reveals only 4 flags up for review:

[image]

The consistency between the actual and indicated is never the same. Perhaps a bug that can be fixed? This might be browser-dependent and/or rely on using browser cookies (not sure). I'm using Google Chrome 19.0.1084.56 m.

Comment: Maybe the yellow count contains all flags, while the red count doesn't contain your own flags and the one you already acted upon. The red count then would require a more complex database query than the yellow count, so possibly SE decided that this is a good way to optimize.

Comment: This seems to have been answered on Meta.SO: [Flag flag with incorrect count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105616/168244)

Comment: @Werner -- yes, there's an accepted "answer" at that location, but it certainly isn't a definitive explanation.  however, this is definitely the same problem i just reported, so the new question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved or explained? I have just started to see these and it is very confusing!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a design-requirement that was [recently removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/168244).