# 10K-tools allow evaluation of already deleted post

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging, 10k-tools, deleted-posts

As of now the following post has a [deleted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96888/5764): [Is it possible to embed a YouTube video using LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14751/5764)

This answer is still visible within the [10K tools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tools) as an item that requires attention, even displayed as being deleted (through the shading/colour):

[image]

This is surely a bug. I'm running Google Chrome 24.0.1312.57 m and have cleared my cache.

A related (currently unanswered bug) regarding 10K tools is: [Review flags doesn't match actual flags](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2554/5764).

<sub>Not sure how reproducible these bugs are.</sub>

Comment: Same here, Firefox on various platforms

Comment: Yup ... I posted about that on meta.so: [10k flags page displays deleted answer, to which I can't add my flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155213)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

10k users were seeing all posts with moderator flags on them, whether they were deleted or not.

Next build corrects this issue, so you shouldn't be seeing deleted posts on the 10k tools unless you are a moderator.